# Windows treats m3u8 link parameters as CMD command from ffmpeg command

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to download m3u8 file using ffmpeg, it was working perfectly until few days ago, it started to behave strangely.

first let me write down how command looks like:

```
ffmpeg -i https://LINK.TO/FILE.m3u8?Policy=eyQ__&Signature=eFI5zA__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJMWS -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4
pause
```

As you can see the link is for m3u8 file, with three parameters, they are  Policy, Signature and Key-Pair-Id.

the expected result must be an mp4 file named output.mp4, but what I see is bunch of error messages, then CMD window closes, This is the error messages:

```
'Signature' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'Key-Pair-Id' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Why does Windows treat them as commands?

you can see clearly that they are just parameters!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does Windows treat them as commands? you can see clearly that they are just parameters!

But they aren't. In cmd.exe, `&` is a [special character](http://web.archive.org/web/20170311052107/https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true) – a *command separator,* similar to `;` in Bash. Its purpose is *specifically* to split your input into three separate commands run one after another.

To avoid this, put the parameter in quotes:

```
ffmpeg -i "https://LINK.TO/FILE.m3u8?Policy=eyQ__&Signature=eFI5zA__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJMWS" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4
```

Comment: Wow, that makes me feel stupid, never thought CMD would do such a thing.
To be honest I took this command from an app, so I didn't realize that & mark might be the cause.